# Is it possible to search for multiple terms in a column by using a LIKE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to understand if the above question is possible. I've been conceptually thinking about it, and basically what I'm looking to do is:

Specify keywords that may appear in a title. Lets use the two terms "Portfolio" and "Mike"

I'm hoping to generate a query that will allow for me to search for when Portfolio is contained within a title, or Mike. These two titles need not to be together.

For instance, if I have a title dubbed: "Portfolio A" and another title "Mike's favorite" I'd like both of these titles to be returned.

The issue I've encountered with using a LIKE statement is the following:

```
 WHERE 1=1
 and rpt_title LIKE ''%'+@report_title+'%'''
```

If I were to input: 'Portfolio,Mike' it would search for the occurrence of just that within a title.

EDIT: I should have been a bit more clear. I believe it's necessary for me to input my variable as 'Portfolio, Mike' in order for it to find the multiple values. Is this possible?

I'm assuming you could maybe use a charindex with a substring and a replace?

Comment: You can do it with an OR and 2 LIKEs.

Comment: Just give "OR" the try ;-). Don't foget the emphasis  ... XX AND   (a like '%xx%' or a like '%b%')

Comment: You will have to use several `LIKE` express with `OR`. Or you can use regular expressions.

Comment: Either should work, but if your table has a lot of data, you might want to look into full-text indexes.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, multiple Like statements with OR will work just fine -- just make sure you use the correct parentheses:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE 1=1
 and (rpt_title LIKE '%Portfolio%' 
 or rpt_title LIKE '%Mike%')
```

However, I might suggest you look into using a full-text search.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: I will research full-text indexing right now... thanks very much!

Comment: @user2191477 -- no problem, glad we could help.

Answer (score 0):

I can propose a solution where you could specify any number of masks, without using multiple LIKE -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (st VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @temp (st)
VALUES ('Portfolio photo'),('- Mike'),('blank'),('else'),('est')

DECLARE @delims VARCHAR(30)
SELECT @delims = '|Portfolio|Mike|' -- %Portfolio% OR %Mike% OR etc.

SELECT t.st
FROM @temp t
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT substr = 
        SUBSTRING(
            @delims, 
            number + 1,
            CHARINDEX('|', @delims, number + 1) - number - 1)
    FROM [master].dbo.spt_values n
    WHERE [type] = N'P'
        AND number <= LEN(@delims) - 1
        AND SUBSTRING(@delims, number, 1) = '|'
) s
WHERE t.st LIKE '%' + s.substr + '%'
```